# Insert string to memory with null character

Tags: attacks, exploit

I'm trying to implement return-to-libc,
here's the code

```
void func(const char *str) {
    char buf[4];
    strcpy(buf,str);
    printf("you entered [%s]\n",buf);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("Need an argument\n");
        return 0;
    }
    func(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is, the address of the `system` function that my pc gives me is of 6 hex digits instead of 8 hex digits (which means the front two digits are zeros), but I use strcpy to copy the string, which terminates copying the string as soon as it encounters null character.

Any ideas how to copy the whole string I pass including the null character ?
Or anything that you feel will help me with this, is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short Answer :**
It's not possible directly in `strcpy`.

---

**Answer :**
Null character is end of string in `strcpy` ! and you can't inject directly null character .

But you can use to shellcode `encoders`/`encryptors`/`compressor` for removing your shellcode null character or you can use other functions with other string terminator. for example `gets` (in gets string terminator is, `0A`)

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void func(const char *str) {
    char buf[4];
    strcpy(buf,str);
    printf("you entered [%s]\n",buf);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("Need an argument\n");
        return 0;
    }
    func(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled your code with the following command.

```
gcc blah.c -o blah
```

Cracked open `gdb`.

```
[ayrx@localhost ~]$ gdb -q blah 
Reading symbols from /home/ayrx/blah...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBB
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/fedora/blah AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBB
you entered [AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBB]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x42424242 in ?? ()
```

Here is the register dump from `gdb`.

```
(gdb) info registers
eax            0x23 35
ecx            0x7fffffde   2147483614 
edx            0x0  0
ebx            0x4e735000   1316179968
esp            0xbffff160   0xbffff160
ebp            0x41414141   0x41414141 
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x42424242   0x42424242
eflags         0x10286  [ PF SF IF RF ]
cs             0x73         115
ss             0x7b         123
ds             0x7b         123
es             0x7b         123
fs             0x0          0
gs             0x33         51
```

As you can see, the `eip` register has been overwritten with the last 4 `B`s from my input.

The final step will be to overwrite the `eip` register to point to the location of your shellcode. Since your buffer is small, you will have to find some other memory location to stash the shellcode. Overwrite the `eip` register to point to that location and you have won. I'll leave that part to you.

Answer (score 1):

So you can't jump directly to `system` in this case. You might consider looking for some other library function that you can jump to that will do something useful for you. Or you can extend this to a generic [return oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming) attack, and jump to a series of code fragments.

In this case, you would look for some (position dependent) code fragments that give you the ability to derive the address of `system` and jump to it. You might look for a gadget which performs the `and` instruction and use `and 0xcc 0x33` to get `0x00` or whatever. You will then need a gadget that then lets you jump to your derived address.